# Installing PyBrain Failed

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.5, pybrain

I am trying to install PyBrain on Windows 8. I followed these very clear instructions: http://blog.habrador.com/2012/11/how-to-install-pybrain-on-windows.html

I first used Python 3, but after some errors and research, I switched to Python 2.7. Again, after running following command: `setup.py install`, I get: "Requested Python version (2.5) is not installed", but I found somewhere that it's 2.5 and up, so 2.7 should be fine.

I downloaded Python 2.5 from here https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5.6/ and tried following the instructions, but I don't get at all what I'm supposed to do with the "-zxvf" stuff.

So if anybody could tell me how to install PyBrain with Python 2.7 or how to get Python 2.5 installed, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: I used pip install pybrain